# mapping a function over years and using a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks something like:

```
ID  text  year  DATE
G45 txt1 2010  01/01/2010
G45 txt2 2011  01/01/2011
G45 txt3 2012  01/01/2012
B78 txt4 2010  01/01/2010
B78 txt5 2011  01/01/2011
C12 txt6 2013  01/01/2013
```

I can collect the years from the `df` above so I will have unique values of:

```
year_to_process <- c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013")
```

I define my function as the following:

1) I filter by year since I am only interested in the cosine calculation from year t to t-1.

2) I put the text into a VCorpus and clean it

3) I compute the cosine matrix

4) I save the cosine matrix to file

```
text_to_cosine <- function(x){
data <- x %>% filter(year == year_to_process | year == year_to_process - 1)
# some additional text cleaning
cosine_matrix <- cosine(data)
saveRDS(cosine_matrix, file = cosine_matrix.rds)
}
```

The code Works when I do something like: `year_to_process <- "2012"`
 however when I try to `map` or `walk` the data I get an error:

> > walk(text_to_cosine, year_to_process) Error in .x[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> >
> > map(text_to_cosine, year_to_process) Error: `.x` is not a vector (closure)

How can I make it so that I can feed in each of the years?

i.e. 
1) Take 2010 data and process

2) Take 2011 and 2010 data and process

3) Take 2012 and 2011 data and process

4) Take 2013 and 2012 data and process

EDIT:

Here is the function

```
text_to_cosine <- function(x){
  data <- x %>% filter(filing_date_year == year_to_process | filing_date_year == year_to_process - 1)
…
}
```

I am now thinking the error is coming from the `filter` part. Could it be that the first year (say 2005) doesn't have a `t-1` and this is causing the error?

EDIT2:

When I apply the following I get the below error:

```
text_to_cosine <- function(x, year_to_process){
  data <- x %>% filter(filing_date_year == year_to_process | filing_date_year == year_to_process - 1)
…
}
```

> text_to_cosine(df, year_to_process)
>   Error in gzfile(file, mode) : invalid 'description' argument In
>   addition: Warning message: In if (file == "") stop("'file' must be
>   non-empty string") :    Show Traceback    Rerun with Debug  Error in
>   gzfile(file, mode) : invalid 'description' argument

Comment: The `year_to_process` seems a character variable not numeric (for -1)? try as.year(year_to_process)

Comment: In my data I have: `> str(year_to_process)
 num [1:10] 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 …`

Comment: Should be `walk(year_to_process, text_to_cosine)`?

Comment: I get this error: `walk(year_to_process, text_to_cosine)
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')" ` I will add an edit to show a little more my actual function.

Comment: Your text_to_process(x) where x is a data.frame not a year that's why the `filter` not applicable. Replace year_to_process with x in your function and name your data frame other than x.

Comment: oooh so I have 3 "inputs". The function `text_to_cosine` a data frame `df` and the years `year_to_process`. When I apply `text_to_cosine(df)` with `year_to_process <- "2010"`the function Works. Perhaps I should add two inputs into the function such as `text_to_cosine <- function(x, year_to_process)` Would this fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem have mixed x and the function's input:

```
text_to_cosine <- function(year_to_process){
    data <- x %>% filter(year == year_to_process | year == year_to_process - 1)
    # some additional text cleaning
    cosine_matrix <- cosine(data)
    saveRDS(cosine_matrix, file = cosine_matrix.rds)
    }
```